# Injecting new constructor parameters every time a type is resolved using unity

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've just come across an issue recently where I want new types injected into the requested type every time it is resolved.

The current code I have to register the type is

```
container.RegisterType<IFirstT, FirstT>();

container.RegisterType<ISecondT, SecondT>();

container.RegisterType<IInjectableT, InjectableT>()
    .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
    .ConfigureInjectionFor<InjectableT>(
          new InjectionConstructor(
                  container.Resolve<IFirstT>(),
                  container.Resolve<ISecondT>(),
           )
    );
```

I've now come to realise that the same injection constructor is being used every time I resolve the *IInjectableT*.

Is it possible that the InjectionConstructor will create new Dependencies everytime with unity?

I realise that I can just resolve the dependencies inside of the constructor of *InjectableT* and achieve the same thing, however I was intending for the IOC to controll this type of behaviour and choose if a new instance should be injected or an existing one passed to it.

Comment: Just found that if I use typeOf(T) instead of container.Resolve<T>() in the InjectionConstructor I get the result I'm after

Comment: If you already resolved the issue, you should either: 1. provide a real answer and accept it so that it's easier to see that this question has been answered. 2. delete the question.

Comment: While it resolved my issue I wanted the best solution known.  I wasn't sure that my answer was the most correct one or just a work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ResolvedParameter:

```
container.RegisterType<IInjectableT, InjectableT>(
          new InjectionConstructor(
                  new ResolvedParameter<IFirstT>(),
                  new ResolvedParameter<ISecondT>()
           )
    );
```