# What's the difference between IUnityContainer.Resolve() and ResolvedParameter when configuring constructor arguments?

Tags: unity-container

Some code I'm updating uses Unity which is a bit new to me, although I get the general principles.

One interface is registered like this:

```
          _container.RegisterType<ISomething, Something>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<ITypeA>(),
                new ResolvedParameter<ITypeB>(),
                _container.Resolve<ITypeC>()
            )
          );
```

I'm confused the distinction between `new ResolvedParameter<ITypeB>()` and `_container.Resolve<ITypeC>()` - can someone make it clearer what the difference is and when each might be used/preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you resolve `ISomething`, new `ITypeA` and new `ITypeB` implementations are instantiated *(assuming they are not registered as singletons)* and passed to constructor. but for `ITypeC` you have the exact instance created when you called `_container.Resolve<ITypeC>()`.

see related question: [Injecting new constructor parameters every time a type is resolved using unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188335/injecting-new-constructor-parameters-every-time-a-type-is-resolved-using-unity)

Comment: That's very clear, one is passing a concrete instance the other is deferring it. Thanks.