# Unity Container returns singleton instead of new instance

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am trying to figure out how Lifetime Managers work. I Registered 2 types and injected one into another(Audi into Driver). I created two Driver instances and it seems they are using the same instance of Audi, when I expected every Driver to have it's own Audi instance (since TransientLifetimeManager is being used).

```
    public interface ICar
    {

        int Run();
    }

    public class Audi : ICar
    {            
        private int _miles = 0;

        public int Run()
        {
            return ++_miles;
        }
    }

    public class Driver
    {
        public ICar _car = null;       
        public Driver(ICar car)
        {
            _car = car;

        }

        public void RunCar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running {0} - {1} mile ", _car.GetType().Name, _car.Run());
        }
    }



container.RegisterType<ICar, BMW>();
container.RegisterType<Driver>(new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<ICar>()));
var driver = container.Resolve<Driver>();
var driver2 = container.Resolve<Driver>();
//False, that's fine.
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(driver,driver2));
//True. Why??
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(driver._car,driver2._car));           

//The situation changes if I don't use InjectionConstructor parameter:
 container.RegisterType<Driver>();
//Now it returns False.
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(driver._car,driver2._car));
```

What is difference? Why the usage of InjectionConstructor changes the behaviour?

Comment: Because when you're using `InjectionConstructor` you're explicitly instructing Unity to use *that* instance of `ICar` you're passing to it. When you don't do that, it opts for `container.Resolve()` *everytime* you're requesting a new instance of `Driver`, as expected.

Comment: Now I see it, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I finally puzzled out what is going on. Thanks haim770 for the explanation.
In my case I had to use `ResolvedParameter<ICar>` instead of `container.Resolve<ICar>()` inside the `InjectionConstructor` to achieve what I wanted.
The difference between `container.Resolve()` and `ResolvedParameter` is not obvious, but this question clarifies it:
[What's the difference between IUnityContainer.Resolve() and ResolvedParameter when configuring constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654950/whats-the-difference-between-iunitycontainer-resolve-and-resolvedparameter-wh)